# Fetching NSManagedObject not saved

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Im trying to fetch some objects that Im parsing from a JSON, I dont want to save them until some actions are being done by the user, but I want to fetch them.
Not saving them means I wont be able to fetch them in an different run of the app, but that's ok.
So Im creating the NSManagedObject like this.

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
NSManagedObject *event = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entityDescription insertIntoManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
```

And then Im trying to fetch it like this.

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id_server == %@", aIdServer];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:testForTrue];

NSArray *arrayEvents = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]];
```

id_server is a unique value, and it never returns an event, that is actually there, because if I print all 'Events' in CoreData it shows the event with the id_server.

If I save the context:

```
NSError *error;
if (![[appDelegate managedObjectContext] save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

It finds the events, but can't I fetch events without saving the context?

Thanks

[EDIT]

The way I access the managedContext is the following:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
     }

      NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
         _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
         [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though all attributes were set correctly, since I printed all values and they were correct, I was doing something weird, setting as a NSString something that originally(from the server)is an int.
When I was saving the context, the fetching was working correctly, but when I didnt that, somehow, became an issue.
Changing the type of that attribute, the one I was fectching, solved the issue.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! I spent the better part of a day today trying to track down a weird bug and after finally coming across this answer I found the problem, I was storing NSNumbers but using a NSString value in the predicate when querying. I was about to resort to a mucky workaround of saving the MOC before any fetchRequest. Thankfully you saved me from that!

Answer (score 0):

The `NSManagedObject` class instances that you create will only remain associated with the `NSManagedObjectContext` that was used to create them until and unless you commit them to persistent store.
So, if you want to fetch the same objects (not saved to persistent store), you will need to have reference to same `NSManagedObjectContext` instance that was used to create them.

In your code, does `[self managedObjectContext]` creates a new managedObjectContext every time it is called or it just returns the same context ?
If it creates a new managedObjectContext everytime then you are getting a new instance of `NSManagedObjectContext` and hence you will not be able to fetch those  `NSManagedObject` instances.

However, if it is returning the same instance of NSManagedObjectContext then you can use

```
[myFetchRequest setIncludesPendingChanges:YES];
```

[Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/index.html)

This matches against currently unsaved changes in the managed object context.

Comment: I added the method where I get the managedContext. It's a lazy load, but I actually it has to do something witht the managedContext, that at some point it changes, but I can't figure out how or why.
I also added setIncludesPendingChanges, but still it doesnt find the event.

Comment: To add more witchcraft to this, if I fetch by another attribute, like name, it then fetchs the appropiate event.

Comment: Can you verify that the 'id_server' property of 'Event' class is being set properly ? Also make sure that the 'aIdServer' that you are testing against in NSPredicate is not 'nil'.